# 3-uniform tetrahedron-free hypergraph on seven vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hypergraph, extremal-graph-theory

My problem concerns 3-uniform hypergraphs. Let $f(n)$ be the maximal number of edges in a 3-uniform hypergraph such that no four edges form a "tetrahedron", i.e., four edges that join the same four digits (the pattern $123, 124, 134, 234$).

Trivially, $f(3)=1$, and $f(4)=3$ (all edges but one so as to not contain the full tetrahedron).

A bound for $f(n)$ can be obtained by counting the number of times each edge must appear in the n sub-hypergraphs on $n-1$ vertices. There are $n$ of these, which contain at most $f(n-1)$ edges each. But each edge is being counted in $n-3$ of these sub-hypergraphs (all except the ones that miss out one of the three vertices it joins). Therefore, we have the equation: $(n-3)f(n)\leq nf(n-1)$.

$2f(5) \leq 5f(4)=15, $ so $f(5)\leq 7$, which can be obtained.

$3f(6) \leq 6f(5)=42, $ so $f(6)\leq 14$, which again can be obtained.

$4f(7) \leq 7f(6)=98, $ so $f(7)\leq 24$. 23 edges on 7 vertices can be achieved, and I have verified computationally that this is optimal. However I'm not satisfied with this, which brings me to my question:

Is there a human proof that every 3-uniform hypergraph with 7 vertices and 24 edges contains a tetrahedron?

EDIT: I received this hint from urotmau:

Go down a dimension and look at the subset of hyperedges sharing a vertex p.  If the subset had 15 hyperedges, any hyperedge avoiding p would complete a tetra. If there were 14, at least one of any five hyperedges missing p would complete a tetra. For thirteen, eight. Continue this analysis down to ten hyperedges, and then make a human proof out of the efforts.

I have been able to make this work. If the subset contains 15, 14, or 13 edges, it works easily to show that there can't be enough vertices. If the number is 12, you need to do some thinking about tetrahedrons in the other allowed edges, but you can actually show that even f(7)=23 is not obtainable here.

11 was quite a bit longer and required a bit of a casebash.

With 10 I was able to cheat and say that if all vertices only have 10 edges maximum, then the number of edges is at most 10*7/3 (7 vertices, and 3 vertices on an edge), and therefore 23 is the maximum.

Interestingly, if you apply the same reasoning to the six vertex version of this problem, you can show (with minimal case work) that the maximal graph is unique. This doesn't seem to work for seven vertices.

Comment: The next two values, f(8) and f(9), are equal to what you would expect from the bound (once f(7)=23 is assumed). f(8)=36, and f(9)=54. f(10) again becomes tricky.

Comment: Just a thought. Call a tetrahedron-free hypergraph on $n$ vertices *slack* if it does not achieve $f(n)$. Then, following your inequalities backwards, any tetrahedron-free graph on 5 vertices has at least one slack 4-verex subgraph, and a tetrahedron-free graph on 7 vertices with 24 edges can have at most 3 slack 5-vertex subgraphs.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A140462

Answer (score 1):

This is the "simplest" hypergraph Turán problem, where I put "simplest" in quotes because there is no such thing as a simple hypergraph Turán problem.

[This paper](https://people.math.sc.edu/lu/papers/turan.pdf) gives a conjecture that has been proved up to 13 vertices, but I don't have easy access to the paper of Spencer which is supposed to have that proof.